# How to install GNOME 3.10 in Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: gnome, 13.10

I am using Ubuntu 13.10. Is it possible to install GNOME 3.10 in it?

Comment: @fossfreedom how is it can be duplicate ?

Comment: same question IMHO - gnome3.10 is the latest, the duplicate asks how to install the latest.

Comment: @fossfreedom gnome 3.10 not available for direct install or any other method mentioned in the above duplicate. so is it  duplicate ?

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate too. Better to close, merge and move the answer to the master question.